# Custom pagination double slash in the url

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm setting up some custom pagination on a wordpress page with the following code:

```
    <?php
    if ($total_users > $total_query) {
      $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
      echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%/',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_next'    => false,
            'type'         => 'list'
        ));
    }
    ?>
```

A tutorial with the following code can be found here (they have the same issues but fail to address a solution).

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/wordpress-pagination-a-primer--wp-24383
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-display-authors-pagination/

The problem happens when you click through multiple pages. The first page will give you a link looking something like this (which is good):

```
http://website.com/page/1/
```

Then when you click on another page the link will become (which is bad, notice the extra slash):

```
http://website.com//page/1/
```

And every page after that will add another slash before the `page/`

If you change `'format' => '/page/%#%/',` to be `'format' => 'page/%#%/',` the first url will look like this:

```
http://website.compage/1/
```

Which will take you to a broken page. However if you manually go to one of the pages and start clicking through, you will no longer get extra slashes.

**Question**

How can I prevent it from adding the extra slashes in the url?